# Panel class in Zurb Ink email on Android not displaying correctly

Tags: android, email, zurb-foundation, zurb-ink

I am trying to use Zurb Ink to create a responsive email layout that uses the panel class to call out a few important items in the email.  In most cases, it displays correctly in tests (using Litmus), except on some of the Android devices. The table extends to the right beyond the viewable area of the screen. In order to make the email display correctly on as many devices as possible, I am using a very simple layout... single columns in every table.

Comment: Some code might be helpful here.

Comment: Please add your code so we can see what you're doing.